# May the second column in a row of theorems be aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, theorems, alignment, ntheorem, newtheorem

Is there a way to align the second column of universalized disjunctions in the following row of theorem like environments?

````
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}


\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
{\topsep}   % above space
{\topsep}   % below space
{\itshape}  % body font
{0pt}       % indent
{\bfseries} % head font
{}         % head punctuation
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
{}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{exercise}

\newtheorem{provlinje}{~}
\renewcommand*{\theprovlinje}{\alph{provlinje}}

\begin{document}
    
    
\textit{Prooflines}



\begin{provlinje}
    $\forall x\alpha(x)$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x)\vee\theta(x))$
\end{provlinje}
\begin{provlinje}
$\forall x(\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x)\vee\theta(x)\vee\iota(x))$
\end{provlinje}

\end{document} ```
````

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a row of theorem-like environments? Wouldn't be an `enumerate` much easier?

Comment: I have to say, 9 of the same environment in a row is a serious code smell.

Comment: @campa I want to use label/ref.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't understand.

Comment: (You can use label/ref with enumerate.  Even better, the `enumitem` package lets you specify the `\labelwidth`.)  [Code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): I don't completely understand what you're doing, but as soon as I looked at it, it didn't look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I would use an `enumerate` environment. Loading the `enumitem` package gives maximum flexibility.

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textit{Prooflines}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*},align=left,ref=\textbf{BLA\alph*}]
\item $\forall x \; \phantom( \alpha(x)$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x))$\label{foo}
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x)\vee\theta(x))$
\item $\forall x \; (\alpha(x)\vee\beta(x)\vee\gamma(x)\vee\delta(x)\vee\epsilon(x)\vee\zeta(x)\vee\eta(x)\vee\theta(x)\vee\iota(x))$
\end{enumerate}
See step \ref{foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]